# Validate Edited data in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, validation

I have an editable JQGrid(inline editing using events). I want to validate the edited data. I tried the following but none works. It submits the data to the server and returns an error.

**Method1:**
editRules: { number: true}

**Method2**
{ name: 'Projection', index: 'Projection', width: 45, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editRules: { custom: true, custom_func: ValidateCell} },

I also tried setting edittype = custom but I don't see why its needed. All I need is to stop the user from entering anything but numbers

Thanks,
Arshya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This s embarrassing!!

I wrote editrules as editRules!!!

all working now!